# Run web2py server on startup linux

Tags: python, linux, startup, web2py

I appreciate if one could help me figure this out. 
I'm trying to tun web2py on startup in a linux machine. I'm simply using a command line added to crontab as follows: @reboot python web2py.py &
I've tested this command for other python scripts like to blink an LED and it works fine. The command python web2py.py itself works fine in the terminal (I've used a default pass in the widget so I don't need to mention it in the command like -a password).
I've read the forums about a problem associated with web2py running on the startup due to cron being disabled. I enabled it, but still did not work. 
Does anyone know what's the problem and could resolve it in past? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `python web2py.py -a '<recycle>'`?

Comment: Yes, I tried adding -a '<recycle>', it did not work.

Comment: Hi, I finally got to know that web2py is best to be used in the startup using system level configuration not as crontab command. 
I read http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/13#One-step-production-deployment and implemented what is said:

Comment: edit "web2py.ubuntu.sh" and replace the "/usr/lib/web2py" 
sudo cp scripts/web2py.ubuntu.sh /etc/init.d/web2py
sudo update-rc.d web2py defaults
sudo /etc/init.d/web2py start
I did change the path in the web2py.ubuntu.sh in line DAEMON_DIR=/path/$NAME; I did not touch other things in this file.

Comment: Then I ran sudo cp scripts/web2py.ubuntu.sh /etc/init.d/web2py and it worked.
Then I ran sudo update-rc.d web2py defaults and got the following:

update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
update-rc.d: warning: default stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match web2py Default-Stop values (S 0 1 6)

finally, when I ran sudo /etc/init.d/web2py start, I got the following error:

[....] Starting web2py (via systemctl): web2py.serviceJob failed. See system journal and 'systemctl status' for details.
 failed!

Comment: correction, when I did the command sudo update-rc.d web2py defaults
I got the following message:
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
update-rc.d: warning: default stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match web2py Default-Stop values (S 0 1 6)
insserv: script web2py is not an executable regular file, skipped!
Since it says skipped, does it mean this was not performed well?